# JSF @ManagedBean not created in certain case

Tags: jsf

I have ManagedBean for application log-in and it's SessionScoped.

```
@ManagedBean(name="loginBean")
@SessionScoped
public class LoginBean implements Serializable {

   private static final long serialVersionUID = 7765876815540798583L;

   private String username;
   private String password;

   ...

   // getters and setters
```

There is a `FileUploadController` and this works fine including `loginBean` injection:

```
@ManagedBean(name="fileUploadController")
public class FileUploadController implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7765485215540798583L;

    @ManagedProperty(value="#{loginBean}")
    private LoginBean loginBean;

    // getters and setters
```

But I have a problem with another bean, similar to this one. It's called `FileDownloadController`

```
package com.simulacije.csis.beans;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedProperty;
import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;

import org.primefaces.model.DefaultStreamedContent;
import org.primefaces.model.StreamedContent;

@ManagedBean(name="fileDownloadController")
@RequestScoped
public class FileDownloadController implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7765876811740798583L;    

    private StreamedContent file;

    @ManagedProperty(value="#{loginBean}")
    private LoginBean loginBean;

    public FileDownloadController() {          
       // File download logic
    }

    public StreamedContent getFile() {
       return file;
    }

    public LoginBean getLoginBean() {
        return loginBean;
    }

    public void setLoginBean(LoginBean loginBean) {
        this.loginBean = loginBean;
    }

}
```

It constantly fires null exception for `loginBean`. Otherwise, download works fine if I remove loginBean, but I need to make this working.
Am i missing something? 
Thanks!

Comment: Check if your imports are correct

Comment: I think Kukeltje means that if you're going to use JSF `ManagedBean`, make sure you use JSF `javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped`.

Comment: I have`javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped` in my source. I've edited question and added all imports. Am I ommiting something?

Comment: Imports for `LoginBean`?

Comment: They are in the same package.